# How to Output Mjpeg from Kokorin Jaffree FFmpeg via UDP to a Localhost Port?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a Java program which displays dual webcams and records them to file in FHD 30fps H264/H265.  It uses Sarxos Webcam for the initial setup and display but when recording, it  switches to Jaffree FFmpeg. During recording Sarxos Webcam must release its webcam access and cannot display while recording continues.

I have tried recording with Xuggler/Sarxos but Sarxos seems to only access raw video from the webcams which creates limitations in the frame rate and resolution which can be achieved.  At 1920x1080 the cameras can only deliver 5 fps raw video.

I am trying to direct mjpeg streams from Jaffree to localports for display purposes during recording but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Simultaneous recording plus sending to a port can be done from the terminal with the following:

```
ffmpeg -f  dshow  -video_size 1920x1080 -rtbufsize 944640k -framerate 25 -vcodec mjpeg  -i video="Logitech Webcam C930e" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 outFHDx25.mp4 -f mpegts udp://localhost:1234?pkt_size=188&buffer_size=65535
```

and viewed from the port in a different terminal like this:

```
ffplay -i udp://localhost:1234
```

The video which displays is a little blocky compared with the video recorded to file.  Any suggestions on how to improve this would be appreciated.

Note that FFPlay is not included in Jaffree FFMpeg.

I would like to send the mjpeg to a port and then read it into the Sarxos Webcam viewer to display while recording is in progress.

The Jaffree Java code for recording the output of one webcam to file follows. It takes the mjpeg/yuv422p output from the webcam and normally encodes it to file as H264/yuv420p:

```
public static FFmpeg createTestFFmpeg() {
      String camera1Ref = "video=" + cam1Vid + ":audio=" + cam1Aud;
          return FFmpeg.atPath()
              .addArguments("-f", "dshow")  //selects dshow for Windows
              .addArguments("-video_size", resString)  //video resolution  eg 1920x1080          
              .addArguments("-rtbufsize", rtBufResultString) 
              .addArguments("-thread_queue_size", threadQ)
              .addArguments("-framerate", fpsString)   // capture frame rate  eg 30fps         
              .addArguments(codec, vidString)  //set capture encode mode from camera
              .addArgument(audio) //on or off
              .addArguments("-i", camera1Ref)   // name of camera to capture
              .addArguments("-pix_fmt", pixFmt)
              .addArguments("-c:v", enc2)  //eg enc2 = "libx264", "h264_nvenc"
              .addArguments(enc3, enc4)  //enc3 = "-crf", enc4 = "20"
              .addArguments(enc5, enc6)  //enc5 = "-gpu:v", enc6 = "0"
              .addArguments(enc7, enc8)  //enc7 = "-cq:v", enc8 = "20"
              .addArguments(enc9, enc10)  //enc9 = "-rc:v", enc10 = "vbr"
              .addArguments(enc11, enc12)  //enc11 = "-tune:v", enc12 = "ll"
              .addArguments(enc13, enc14)  //enc13 = "-preset:v", enc14 = "p1" 
              .addArguments(enc15,enc16)  //enc15 = "-b:v", enc16 = "0"
              .addArguments(enc17, enc18)  //enc17 = "-maxrate:v", enc18 = "5000k"
              .addArguments(enc19, enc20)  //enc19 = "-bufsize:v", enc20 = "5000k"
              .addArguments(enc21, enc22)  //enc21 = "-profile:v", enc22 = "main"
              .addArgument(noFFStats) //"-nostats"{, stops logging progress/statistics
              .addArguments("-loglevel", ffLogLevel)  //error logging
              .addArgument(bannerResultString)  // "-hide_banner"
              .addArguments("-rtbufsize", rtBufResultString) 
              .setOverwriteOutput(true)   // overwrite filename if it exists  Boolean = overwriteFile
              .addOutput(
                  UrlOutput
                      .toUrl(filePathL))                    
              .setProgressListener(new ProgressListener(){
                  @Override
                  public void onProgress(FFmpegProgress progress){
                     if(ffProgress){ 
                          System.out.println(progress);
                          
                     } 
                    }
            } );
            
   }
```

How and where do I add the code to output mjpeg via UDP to a localport while simultaneously writing H264 to a file, and what is the syntax?  I am sure it must be simple but I seem to have tried all of the permutations without success. I can write to a file OR I can output to a port but I cannot do both.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works. FHD H264 30fps is recorded to file and 5fps mjpeg is output to localhost port 1234 (30 fps works but uses much more cpu).

```
public static FFmpeg createTestFFmpeg() {
        String camera1Ref = "video=" + cam1Vid + ":audio=" + cam1Aud;
        String fileName = "udp://localhost:1234?pkt_size=1316&buffer_size=65535";
        return FFmpeg.atPath()
              .addArguments("-f", "dshow")
              //input parameters
              .addArguments("-video_size", resString)
              .addArguments("-rtbufsize", rtBufResultString) 
              .addArguments("-thread_queue_size", threadQ)
              .addArguments("-framerate", fpsString)
              .addArguments(codec, vidString)
              .addArgument(audio)
              .addArguments("-i", camera1Ref)

              //output parameters
              
              .addArguments("-pix_fmt", pixFmt)
              .addArguments("-c:v", enc2)
              .addArguments(enc3, enc4)
              .addArguments(enc5, enc6)  //enc5/6
              .addArguments(enc7, enc8)  //enc7/8
              .addArguments(enc9, enc10)  //enc9/10
              .addArguments(enc11, enc12)  //enc11/12
              .addArguments(enc13, enc14)  //enc13/14
              .addArguments(enc15,enc16)  //enc15/16
              .addArguments(enc17, enc18)  //enc17/18
              .addArguments(enc19, enc20)  //enc19/20
              .addArguments(enc21, enc22)  //enc21/22
              .addArgument(noFFStats)
              .addArguments("-loglevel", ffLogLevel)
              .addArgument(bannerResultString)
              .addArguments("-rtbufsize", rtBufResultString) // remove this?
              .setOverwriteOutput(true)
              
              //output to file
               .addArgument(filePathL)  //using .addOutput here stops following lines from executing
              
               // output to port
               .addArguments("-r", "5")  //frame rate = 5 cpu ~15%, fps=30 gives cpu ~50%
               //.addArguments("-c:v", "libx264") //cpu ~50% but VG pic Q else blocky
               //.addArguments("-c", "copy") //doesn't work
               .addArguments("-f", "mpegts")
               .addArgument(fileName)
 
               .setProgressListener(new ProgressListener(){
                     
                      @Override
                      public void onProgress(FFmpegProgress progress){
                       if(ffProgress){   
                          System.out.println(progress);
                          
                        }   
                    }
                }); 

          
      }
```

Output to port can be viewed with FFPlay as described previously or with VLC ->media->open network stream->enter network URL = udp://@:1234